# Rse rsync with option spectified format

Tags: rsync, cwrsync

i began to learn rsync on centos and i have a question. i have two host, i want use rsync update video from host1 to host 2, but only update specified format example MP4,FLV. on host1 have many different format. 
please help me!thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `--exclude`/`--include` construct where you include the wanted extensions but exclude everything else.

```
rsync -av --include='*.flv' --include='*.mp4' --exclude='*' /source /destination
```